# Writing a method that outputs a different uniqe permutation of a number every time it's called

Tags: java, algorithm, random, hashtable, permutation

I got this interview question and I am still very confused about it.
The question was as the title suggest, i'll explain.

You are given a random creation function to use.

the function input is an integer n. let's say I call it with 3.

it should give me a permutation of the numbers from 1 - 3. so for example it will give me 2, 3 , 1.

after i call the function again, it won't give me the same permutation, now it will give me 1, 2, 3 for example.

Now if i will call it with n = 4. I may get 1,4,3,2.

Calling it with  3 again will not output 2,3,1 nor 1,2,3 as was outputed before, it will give me a different permutation out of the 3! possible permutations.

I was confused about this question there and I still am now. How is this possible within normal running time ? As I see it, there has to be some static variable that remembers what was called before or after the function finishes executing.
So my thought is creating a static hashtable (key,value) that gets the input as key and the value is an array of the length of the n!. 
Then we use the random method to output a random instance out of these and move this instance to the back, so it will not be called again, thus keeping the output unique.

The space time complexity seems huge to me.
Am I missing something in this question ?

Comment: Does it need to be different, or just may be a different ordering?  If it's required to be different, you may be able to have an int store a key to use to generate the next iteration

Comment: You might want to store your used permutations in a trie, so you can quickly find unused paths down the tree.

Comment: See for example [Next lexicographical permutation algorithm](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm). I just googled for "lexicographic order permutations". There are other articles. It is a well known problem.

Comment: Permutation generators are covered quite well on line; there are even several examples on Stack Overflow.  Given these resources, how are you stuck finding an algorithm?

Comment: The problem is not generating a permutation. the problem is the space complexity to store all this permutations that were generated

Comment: The answer I posted uses a much smaller space to determine how to make a new permutation.  To get old ones, one can simply backtrack with the seed that's being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan Rosenne's answer was downvoted because it was link-only, but it is still the  right answer in my opinion, being that this  is such a well-known problem. You can also see a minimal explanation in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order.

To address your space-complexity concern, generating permutations in lexicographical ordering has O(1) space complexity, you don't need to store nothing other than the current permutation. The algorithm is quite simple, but most of all, its correctness is quite intuitive. Imagine you had the set of all permutations and you order them lexicographically. Advancing to the next in order and then cycling back will give you the maximum cycle without repetitions. The problem with that is again the space-complexity, since you would need to store all possible permutations; the algorithm gives you a way to get the next permutation without storing anything. It may take a while to understand, but once I got it it was quite enlightening.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the answer, an edit may have been more fitting

Comment: You may be right, I don't regularly answer on SO, it just seemed strange to add such a long comment

Comment: Instead of a comment, you can click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47063112/edit) on the post (it's located in the bottom left, next to share and flag)

Comment: And modify another answer? No idea I could do that, isn't it considered disrespectful or something?

Comment: Not at all, if you can improve the answer it's greatly encouraged.  If the edit is approved you even get reputation for it.  It helps the website if questions and answers have better content and are easier to understand

Comment: Thanks, approved your answer as It encouraged me to understand it and I wish you would answer more questions in SO furtheron

Answer (score 1):

You can store a static variable as a seed for the next permutation

In this case, we can change which slot each number will be put in with an int (for example this is hard coded to sets of 4 numbers)

```
private static int seed = 0;

public static int[] generate()
{
    //s is a copy of seed, and increment seed for the next generation
    int s = seed++ & 0x7FFFFFFF; //ensure s is positive
    int[] out = new int[4];

    //place 4-2
    for(int i = out.length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int pos = s % i;
        s /= i;
        for(int j = 0; j < out.length; j++)
            if(out[j] == 0)
                if(pos-- == 0)
                {
                    out[j] = i;
                    break;
                }
    }

    //place 1 in the last spot open
    for(int i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
        if(out[i] == 0)
        {
            out[i] = 1;
            break;
        }

    return out;
}
```

Here's a version that takes the size as an input, and uses a HashMap to store the seeds

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> seeds = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public static int[] generate(int size)
{
    //s is a copy of seed, and increment seed for the next generation
    int s = seeds.containsKey(size) ? seeds.get(size) : 0; //can replace 0 with a Math.random() call to seed randomly
    seeds.put(size, s + 1);
    s &= 0x7FFFFFFF; //ensure s is positive
    int[] out = new int[size];

    //place numbers 2+
    for(int i = out.length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int pos = s % i;
        s /= i;
        for(int j = 0; j < out.length; j++)
            if(out[j] == 0)
                if(pos-- == 0)
                {
                    out[j] = i;
                    break;
                }
    }

    //place 1 in the last spot open
    for(int i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
        if(out[i] == 0)
        {
            out[i] = 1;
            break;
        }

    return out;
}
```

This method works because the seed stores the locations of each element to be placed

For size 4:

1. Get the lowest digit in base 4, since there are 4 slots remaining
2. Place a `4` in that slot
3. Shift the number to remove the data used (divide by 4)
4. Get the lowest digit in base 3, since there are 3 slots remaining
5. Place a `3` in that slot
6. Shift the number to remove the data used (divide by 3)
7. Get the lowest digit in base 2, since there are 2 slots remaining
8. Place a `2` in that slot
9. Shift the number to remove the data used (divide by 2)
10. There is only one slot remaining
11. Place a `1` in that slot

This method is expandable up to 12! for ints, 13! overflows, or 20! for longs (21! overflows)

If you need to use bigger numbers, you may be able to replace the seeds with `BigInteger`s